# Why is the GET request for static files returning 404, except for base.css which returns a 200

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am in the process of deploying a simple website written with Django to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Everything seems to be working, except for some of my static resources (CSS + image files) returning 404 errors.

I have run `python manage.py collectstatic` to organize all my static resources as follows:

```
-project
       |-...
       |-static
       |      |-admin  
       |      |    |-...
       |      |    
       |      |-app1
       |      |    |-style.css
       |      |    |-img1
       |      |  
       |      |-app2
       |      |    |-style.css
       |      |
       |      |-project
       |      |       |-base.css
       |-...
```

I have identified two EB logs:

`"GET /static/project/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200`

`"GET /static/app1/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404`

`base.css` is served up fine, but when attempting to retrieve `app/style.css`, I get an error, despite the path matching the structure I have above. Any reason why this would be?

Comment: Are you using Nginx?

Comment: It seems like Elastic Beanstalk does use Nginx: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html

Comment: did you call `manage.py collectstatic` ? is the web server (nginx or apache or other) configured to serve this static directory that contains the collected statics?

Comment: Yes, called collectstatic

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the web server being configured, I was under the impression EB was basically an out-of-the-box deployment solution. How would I check that?

Comment: What is your `STATICFILES_DIRS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS` = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

Comment: `STATIC_URL` = '/static/'
`STATIC_ROOT` = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")